# How to double the lenght of a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, smoothing, lerp

I have an array test {1, 2, 4} and want to pass it in a function IncreaseResolution(float[,] origin) which should increase the length of the array. So basically I want to turn test {1, 2, 4} into test {1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4}. So what I want to do is take the initial array and add a value in between every value for the new array.

Also how could I do this but with a 2D array?

Sketch of how I want to smooth the array:
[image: Sketch of how I want to smooth the array]

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work:

```
public float[] IncreaseResolution(float[] origin)
{
    float[] dest = new float[origin.Length * 2 - 1];

    dest[0] = origin[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < origin.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        float mid = origin[i] + (origin[i + 1] - origin[i]) / 2;
        dest[i * 2 + 1] = mid;
        dest[i * 2 + 2] = origin[i + 1];
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Typo? Shouldn't `mid` be `float mid = (origin[i + 1] + origin[i])/2;` what I see above is the `delta` and not the `mid`.

Comment: almost right. I have edited

Comment: You know that `origin[i] + (origin[i + 1] - origin[i]) / 2 = (origin[i + 1] + origin[i])/2` so I was correct.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the question fully you want to deploy some kind of interpolation function to fill in values between the original grid nodes.**

So is the question how to do the interpolation, or how to resize the array? Because, if you know the interpolation then you just create a new empty array of double size and do the math to fill in the values. As of this time, **the math you want to use is not specified in the question** and hence the question cannot be answered fully.

The example indicates a linear interpolation between nodes, but the values correspond to a parabola, so the end result would not be smooth at all.

Increasing the resolution of `{1,2,4}` with a smooth curve results in `{1, 1.375, 2, 2.875, 4}` as points of the curve 1+**x**/2+**x**<sup>2</sup>/2.

To illustrate the point, here is propose interpolation points from the question, overlayed to the smooth curve that goes through the original points.

[image: fig1]

You see how the new points are off the curve when `{1,1.5,2,3,4}` is used?

---

**The following just answers the question on how to increase the size of 1D and 2D arrays and keep existing values if possible.**

### 1D

For 1D primitive types, use `Array.Copy()`

```
public static T[] Resize<T>(this T[] matrix, int newSize)
{
    var result = new T[newSize];
    Array.Copy(matrix, result, Math.Min(matrix.Length, result.Length));
    return result;
}
```

with the following example code

```
float[] test = new[] { 1f, 2f, 3f };
float[] bigger = Resize(test, 2 * test.Length);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bigger));
// 1,2,3,0,0,0
```

### 2D

The problem with 2D arrays is the memory layout. They are row-major and are stored in memory row by row.

For example, the following 2D array is stored in memory as such

```
| a1 a2 |
| a3 a4 | => { .. a1, a2, a3, a4, ... }
```

So if you want to add a row, you can just append the array. But to add a column, you need to insert values between `a2` and `a3` for example

```
| a1 a2 b1 |
| a3 a4 b2 | => { .. a1, a2, b1, a3, a4, b2, ... }
```

So the above cannot be done with an `Array.Copy()` operation anymore.

This means that the code below adds rows, but not columns

```
public static T[,] Resize<T>(this T[,] matrix, int newRows)
{
    var result = new T[newRows, matrix.GetLength(1)];
    Array.Copy(matrix, result, Math.Min(matrix.Length, result.Length));
    return result;
}
```

To do this 2D resizing, you need to go row by row and copy the old data for each row

```
public static T[,] Resize<T>(this T[,] matrix, int newRows, int newColumns)
{
    var result = new T[newRows, newColumns];
    int oldRows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int oldColumns = matrix.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(oldRows, newRows); i++)
    {
        Array.Copy(matrix, i * oldColumns, result, i * newColumns, Math.Min(oldColumns, newColumns));
    }
    return result;
}
```

with the following demo code

```
var test = new[,] { { 1f, 2f }, { 3f, 4f } };
var bigger = Resize(test, 4, 4);

for (int i = 0; i < bigger.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bigger.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write($" {bigger[i, j],-6}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and output

```
 1      2      0      0
 3      4      0      0
 0      0      0      0
 0      0      0      0
```

### Jagged 2D Array

Often in scientific computing one might use jagged arrays (arrays of arrays) because it is easier to do linear algebra. Here is a similar library function for jagged arrays.

```
public static T[][] Resize<T>(this T[][] matrix, int newRows, int newColumns)
{
    var result = new T[newRows][];
    int oldRows = matrix.Length;
    int oldColumns = oldRows>0 ? matrix[0].Length : 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(oldRows, newRows); i++)
    {
        result[i] = Resize(matrix[i], newColumns);
    }
    for (int i = oldRows; i < newRows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new T[newColumns];
    }
    return result;
}
```